# Geometric property Power of circle

Tags: geometry, circles

A circle with center C is cut by a line through origin O at P and Q. If M is mid-point of PQ, show that $ OM^2 - MP^2 $ is constant for all inclinations of $OP$ and equals its power ( square of tangent ) from O.

EDIT1:

The motivation in posting is that  in my present view this geometrical result  should rank at par with the  Pythagorean theorem:

$$ a^2 + b^2 = const., \,\, c^2 - d^2 = const. \, $$

and that it may have significance in hyperbolic geometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitional if you factor $OM^2 - MP^2$ as a difference of two squares.
Power can be defined as $OP \times OQ$ or as square-of-tangent, different books do it differently, but most books prove that the two quantities are the same.

Comment: But I am sure they don't teach this in school geometry, like the segments product,

Comment: Perhaps.  But in that case ignoring the words "different books do it differently" will provide an equally good and slightly shorter answer.  $OP \times OQ = OT^2$ is in practically any geometry textbook.

Comment: The algebra is elementary, the squares difference is new to me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Is the locus of $M$ a circle? Has it any special name ?

Comment: Nice question and probably not difficult.  Why not post it?

Answer (score 0):

WLOG the equation of the circle $$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$$ and the equation of the straight line through origin $$y=mx$$

If $P(x_1,y_1),Q(x_2,y_2);
  M\left(\dfrac{x_1+x_2}2,\dfrac{y_1+y_2}2\right)$

$y_1=mx_1,y_2=mx_2$

$$\implies(x-a)^2+(mx-b)^2=r^2\iff(1+m^2)x^2-2x(a+mb)+a^2+b^2-r^2=0$$

$x_1\cdot x_2=\dfrac{a^2+b^2-r^2}{1+m^2}$

$$OM^2=\left(0-\dfrac{x_1+x_2}2\right)^2+\left(0-\dfrac{y_1+y_2}2\right)^2=\dfrac{(1+m^2)(x_1+x_2)^2}4$$

$$MP^2=\left(x_1-\dfrac{x_1+x_2}2\right)^2+\left(y_1-\dfrac{y_1+y_2}2\right)^2=\dfrac{(1+m^2)(x_1-x_2)^2}4$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks, this results in $ a^2+b^2-r^2$, the power.

Comment: @Narasimham, My pleasure. which is the square of the length of the tangent